# Django foreign key selection

Tags: python, django, foreign-keys

I am making a simple Django application that records the performance of running athletes. The models for the application look like this:

```
class Athlete(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    nationality = models.CharField(max_length=30)

class TrainingSession(models.Model):
    training_date = models.DateTimeField()
    location = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    athlete = models.ForeignKey(Athlete)

class Run(models.Model):
    run_time = models.IntegerField()
    training = models.ForeignKey(TrainingSession)
```

An athlete has multiple training sessions and in each of those sessions, the athlete runs multiple times (each time, his time will be recorded in seconds).

I found out that I can easily make queries between these models, however, I still struggle with the following problem:
I want to select the runners that CONSISTENTLY run between for example 20 and 30 seconds. When I select runners like this:

```
athletes = Athlete.filter(trainingsession__run__run_time__range=[20,30]).distinct()
```

I get all athletes that once ran between 20 and 30 seconds, but also athletes that once ran 35 seconds. Can you help me to solve this? Hopefully, there's a Django query that makes this easy!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find one more queryset of athletes who ran in `<20` or `>30` seconds and exclude them from your `athletes` queryset. you can use [Q()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/queries/#q-objects)
to perform an `OR` query.

```
excluded_athletes = Athlete.filter(Q(trainingsession__run__run_time__gte=30)|Q(trainingsession__run__run_time__lte=20)).distinct().values_list('id',flat=True)
athletes = Athlete.filter(trainingsession__run__run_time__range=[20,30]).distinct()
athletes.exclude(id__in=excluded_athletes)
```

Answer (score 0):

Q objects can help build more complex queries:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects

Maybe something like this:

```
athletes = Athlete.filter(
    Q(trainingsession__run__run_time__gt=20) & 
    Q(trainingsession__run__run_time__lt=30)).distinct()
```

Also there are some gotchas when using `.distinct()`. Order plays a role, and you can specify what fields to distinct on.
See the docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.distinct